# Dockerfile : not able to use add to map local file to container

Tags: ejabberd, docker, lxc

I am trying to build an ejabberd container and trying to add 2 files from my build directory while creating the container.

```
add ./scripts/ /src
```

However, I keep getting the error: `./scripts folder does not exist`

I am new to docker and was hoping for some help.

Thanks,
Arup

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for using ADD in Dockerfile is:

```
ADD <source> <destination>
```

And ADD has to be in Capital Letters and `<source>`must be the path to a file or directory relative to the source directory being built (also called the context of the build). So if I wanted to add a file, say "localfile.ext" into a destination folder called "scripts" in the containers, my code in the Dockerfile would be like this:

```
RUN mkdir /scripts
ADD localfile.ext /scripts/
```

The trailing / in `/scripts/` tells Docker to treat it as a folder else without that `/scripts` will be treated as a file.

Hope it Helps.